# Reverse for 'cbvdetail' not found. 'cbvdetail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

i can't call my detail class using reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse

```
from . models import Task
from . forms import Taskform
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView



class Tasklistview(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'task'

class Detailview(DetailView):
    model=Task
    template_name = "details.html"
    context_object_name = 'task'

class Updateview(UpdateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = "update.html"
    context_object_name = "task"
    fields = ('name', 'priority', 'date')
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("cbvdetail",kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='todoapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    # path('details', views.details,name='ere')
    path('delete/<int:id>/',views.delete,name='delete'),
    path('edit/<int:id>/',views.update,name='update'),
    path('cbvhome/',views.Tasklistview.as_view(),name='home'),                                                        
        path('cbvdetail/<int:pk>/',views.Detailview.as_view(),name='cbvdetail'),
   
   
  path('cbvupdate/<int:pk>/',views.Updateview.as_view(),name='edit'),


]
```

i want to resolve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662126/reverse-for-index-not-found-index-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or-pattern-n)

Answer (score 1):

You specified an `app_name` in the `urls.py` file. That means you need to prefix the name of the view with that app label, so:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('todoapp:cbvdetail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})
```

If you override `get_success_url`, it does not make much sense to work with `reverse_lazy`, since that method will (normally) only be triggered in case the urls are already loaded, you can thus work with:

```
from django.urls import reverse

# ⋮

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('todoapp:cbvdetail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})
```